# Q: Vector Spaces and Basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

I am fairly new to linear algebra and am trying my best to keep everything straight. That being said, I have a question on the following:

Consider the following set of polynomials:
$$P = \{1, x^2, x^4, x^6 \} $$ and the set created by spanning the elements of P: $$U = \text{span}(P)$$
*Show that $U$ is a vector space. **The span of $P$ is always a vector space correct? So how do you properly show this? Would simply giving an example of being closed under addition and scalar multiplication be sufficient?**

*Consider the linear operator $T$, defined on $U$ such that $$Tu = v = \frac {du}{dx}$$
for all $u \in U$. Identify the vector space $V$ into which the above define operator maps into, such that
$$T: U \to V$$

**What is this exactly looking for? I can easily take the derivative of P(?) Is that the same as the derivative of the $\text{span}(P)$? But that just gives me another vector... Is that considered an 'operator'?**

*Identify a basis for $U$ ($\beta _U$) and a basis for $V$ ($\beta _V$) to then identify a matrix representation $A$ of the linear operator $T$ so that for each $u \in U$ and $v \in V$ such that $v = Tu$ there is:

$$A[u]_{\beta _U} = [v]_{\beta _V}$$

**Isn't $P$ a basis for $U$? Or do you have to include $\{x, x^3, x^5\}$ as well since $P$ is at most $x^6$? This doesn't make too much sense to me though, because how would you create a linear combination of any of the terms $\{x, x^3, x^5\}$? Unless they're always zero? In a similar vein, $\{1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5\}$ wouldn't be a basis for $V$ correct?**

Comment: 1) I think it’s asking you to prove that it satisfies the axioms of a vector space. Do not “prove” that it is closed under addition “by example”.

Comment: 2) Yes, the derivative is a linear operator that will take the vectors from $U$ into another vector space. You need to define that space.

Comment: 3) Yes, $P$ is a basis for $U$, and you can use that basis if you want for $U$. Then you need a basis for $V$. Depending on your choices, you then need to define the matrix representation of differentiation.

Comment: @Joe that makes more sense! Thanks for the helpful hints

Comment: 4) correct, that is not a basis for $V$. The basis will have 3 vectors.

Comment: You’re welcome. It sounds like you already have a very good understanding of the material. Good luck!

Comment: @Joe I'm getting there, I am very used to systems of equations and transitioning to linear algebra is quirky for me at times. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

1. You show that something is a vector space by verifying that it satisfies the definition of a vector space. Showing that a set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication is sufficient only when that set is contained in a known vector space.
2. It's asking for a vector space $V$ that contains the range of $T$. You have to figure out what the range of $T$ is, and verify that it is a vector space.

   You can't take the derivative of $P$ or $span(P)$. You can take the derivative of the elements in $P$ or $span(P)$.

   Yes, $T$ would be considered a (linear) operator.
3. Yes, your intuition is correct. If you add $\{x,x^3,x^5\}$ to the basis, then as you have said, the coefficients next to $x$, $x^3$ and $x^5$ in any linear combination of elements of $U$ would always be $0$, so you would be representing $U$ as a subspace of the vector space with $\{1,x,\dots,x^6\}$ as its basis.