# Q: Matrix Representation of a Linear Operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

[Related Previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3422406/q-vector-spaces-and-basis)

I have a follow-up question related to my previous submission, specifically in regards to solving for the matrix representation $A$ of the linear operator $T$

I am looking to solve for $A$ in the following:
$$A[u]_{\beta _U} = [v]_{\beta _V}$$

where I chose the basis of $U$ to be:
$$\beta _U = \{1, x^2, x^4, x^6\}$$
and the basis for $V$ to be:
$$\beta _V = \{x, x^3, x^5\}$$
Now, formulating the equation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    c_0 & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
    c_4 & c_5 & c_6 & c_7 \\
    c_8 & c_9 & c_{10} & c_{11}
\end{bmatrix} [u]_{\beta _U} = [v]_{\beta _V}
$$
where A is known to be a 3x4 matrix and $[u]_{\beta _U}$ and $[v]_{\beta _V}$ are directly related to the coefficients of:
$$P = \{1, x^2, x^4, x^6 \} $$ where $U = \text{span}(P)$

and $$Tu = v = \frac {du}{dx}$$
with $$v = \{2x, 4x^3, 6x^5\}$$

**My question is:**

How do you solve for the matrix $A$ when the bases are not common?
My first thought would be the first row of matrix $A$ would consist of:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

but this doesn't make sense to me because $c_0$ would be related to the first element of the basis $\beta _U$, which is not the same as the first element of basis $\beta _V$

Any clarity would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You can try thinking of the space $\operatorname{Span} \{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6\}$. Then $T$ will be represented by some square matrix.

Comment: A simpler (IMO) way to approach problems like this one: the columns of the matrix are the images of the “input” basis vectors, expressed in coordinates relative to the “output” basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS you said the vector $(1,x^2,x^4,x^6) \mapsto (2x,4x^3,6x^5) $.

Usually when we consider a certain base for a vector space with $n$ dimension say the basis are $\{ e_1 , e_2 ,\cdots , e_n\}$ then we mean by a vector in $V$ as $(a_1 , a_2 , \cdots , a_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i e_i $. We write each base vector to where it maps. The basis for $U$ are $(1,0,0,0) $ represent $1$ , $(0,1,0,0)$ represent $x^2$, $(0,0,1,0)$ represent $x^4$ and $(0,0,0,1)$ represent $x^6$.

The first vector maps to $0$ vector the second $(0,1,0,0)\mapsto (2,0,0)$ since $x^2 \mapsto 2x$ and $x$ in $V$ is the base $(1,0,0)$ so $2x$ is $(2,0,0)$. We get the following

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    c_0 & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
    c_4 & c_5 & c_6 & c_7 \\
    c_8 & c_9 & c_{10} & c_{11}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    c_0 & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
    c_4 & c_5 & c_6 & c_7 \\
    c_8 & c_9 & c_{10} & c_{11}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 2\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    c_0 & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
    c_4 & c_5 & c_6 & c_7 \\
    c_8 & c_9 & c_{10} & c_{11}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0\\4\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    c_0 & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
    c_4 & c_5 & c_6 & c_7 \\
    c_8 & c_9 & c_{10} & c_{11}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\0 \\1 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\6 \end{bmatrix}$$

Each base maps into a certain vector.

Comment: How is the solution to $A$ not somewhat arbitrary in the above? Couldn’t  any of $(c_0, c_1, c_2, c_3)$ be 2 as long as the others are zero? I guess my question is how $A$ is actually representing differentiation when the LHS -> RHS bases change

Comment: Opps I made a terrible mistake I will fix it.

Comment: If you solve the first you get $c_0=c_4=c_8 = 0 $

Comment: If you solve the second you get $c_1= 2, c_5 =c_9 = 0$

Comment: That makes sense! I appreciate the edit and the further explanation!